# how to detect when my cursor is on open windows with C#

Tags: c#, wpf

I want to do something when my cursor is on an open window with C# WPF. How shoould I do this? I have some ideas, but I'm not sure.

1. Should I detect open windows first? and how?
2. How should I detect when my cursor is on open windows?

This will be idea:

```
if ( cursor is on any open window( How to do this? ) ) {
    I will do something here
}
else {
    I will do something here 
}
```

Comment: Are those open windows from your application or do you mean any open window from any application?

Comment: Is this another attempt at creating an aim-bot?

Comment: these windows will be any open window from any application.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need some WinAPI:

```
static class NativeMethods
{
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    public static extern IntPtr WindowFromPoint(POINT point);

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    public static extern IntPtr GetParent(IntPtr hWnd);

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    public static extern bool GetCursorPos(ref POINT lpPoint);
}

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct POINT
{
    public int x;
    public int y;

    public POINT(int x, int y)
    {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }
}
```

You can get list of WPF app windows from `Application.Current.Windows` property and get their handles using `WindowInteropHelper` class:

```
    public static Window GetWindowFromPoint(Point point)
    {
        var hwnd = NativeMethods.WindowFromPoint(new POINT((int)point.X, (int)point.Y));
        if(hwnd == IntPtr.Zero) return null;
        var p = NativeMethods.GetParent(hwnd);
        while(p != IntPtr.Zero)
        {
            hwnd = p;
            p = NativeMethods.GetParent(hwnd);
        }
        foreach(Window w in Application.Current.Windows)
        {
            if(w.IsVisible)
            {
                var helper = new WindowInteropHelper(w);
                if(helper.Handle == hwnd) return w;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    public static Window GetWindowFromMousePosition()
    {
        POINT p = new POINT();
        NativeMethods.GetCursorPos(ref p);
        return GetWindowFromPoint(new Point(p.x, p.y));
    }
```

Usage:

```
if(GetWindowFromMousePosition() != null)
{
    // mouse cursor is over window
}
else
{
    // mouse cursor is somewhere else
}
```

Update:

Since you want to check windows outside your app, it's even easier:

```
public static bool IsCursorOverWindow()
{
    POINT p = new POINT();
    NativeMethods.GetCursorPos(ref p);
    var hwnd = NativeMethods.WindowFromPoint(p);
    if(hwnd == IntPtr.Zero) return false;
}
```

Comment: If I use these codes as is, can it work as my idea? I mean which part is detecting the mouse is over the window? can you make it easier like the idea above I wrote?

Example:

if(mouse is over)
do sth


So: should I use as you write ?

Comment: I just tried your code like this, but this is not working... Do I do something wrong? This is the whole code with additions:

Comment: You are checking this condition only once in `MainWindow` constructor. At that time window is not visible and cursor can't be over it. Even if there are other windows, this code checks condition only once and you cursor must be precisely over one of them when `MainWindow` constructor is called.

Comment: thanks for your help again, but whereever I put your update, it gives red underline...So, what will be the usage of this? Should I delete one of the things ? where should I place your code? I just put it right above " public MainWindow() " ... When I am done with this task, 80% of the task will be done...huhh...im looking for your answers...

Comment: Or if you tell me what the refence will be for IsCursorOverWindow(), it will be also ok. I couldnt solve the problem yet. Thanks...

Answer (score 0):

```
 using System;
 using System.Collections.Generic;
 using System.Linq;
 using System.Text;
 using System.Windows;
 using System.Windows.Controls;
 using System.Windows.Data;
 using System.Windows.Documents;
 using System.Windows.Input;
 using System.Windows.Media;
 using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
 using System.Windows.Navigation;
 using System.Windows.Shapes;
 using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
 using System.Windows.Interop;
 using System.IO;
 using System.Windows.Forms;



 namespace WpfApplication6
 {
/// <summary>
/// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
/// </summary>
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    static extern void mouse_event(int dwFlags, int dx, int dy, int dwData, int dwExtraInfo);

    [Flags]
    public enum MouseEventFlags
    {
        LEFTDOWN = 0x00000002,
        LEFTUP = 0x00000004,
        MIDDLEDOWN = 0x00000020,
        MIDDLEUP = 0x00000040,
        MOVE = 0x00000001,
        ABSOLUTE = 0x00008000,
        RIGHTDOWN = 0x00000008,
        RIGHTUP = 0x00000010
    }

    public static void LeftClick(int X, int Y)
    {
        System.Windows.Forms.Cursor.Position = new System.Drawing.Point(System.Windows.Forms.Cursor.Position.X, System.Windows.Forms.Cursor.Position.Y);
        mouse_event((int)(MouseEventFlags.LEFTDOWN), 0, 0, 0, 0);
    }

    public static void LeftClickRelease(int X, int Y)
    {
        System.Windows.Forms.Cursor.Position = new System.Drawing.Point(System.Windows.Forms.Cursor.Position.X, System.Windows.Forms.Cursor.Position.Y);

        mouse_event((int)(MouseEventFlags.LEFTUP), 0, 0, 0, 0);
    } 



    static class NativeMethods
    {
        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        public static extern IntPtr WindowFromPoint(POINT point);

        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        public static extern IntPtr GetParent(IntPtr hWnd);

        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        public static extern bool GetCursorPos(ref POINT lpPoint);
    }

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    public struct POINT
    {
        public int x;
        public int y;

        public POINT(int x, int y)
        {
            this.x = x;
            this.y = y;
        }
    }

    public static Window GetWindowFromPoint(Point point)
    {
        var hwnd = NativeMethods.WindowFromPoint(new POINT((int)point.X, (int)point.Y));
        if (hwnd == IntPtr.Zero) return null;
        var p = NativeMethods.GetParent(hwnd);
        while (p != IntPtr.Zero)
        {
            hwnd = p;
            p = NativeMethods.GetParent(hwnd);
        }
        foreach (Window w in System.Windows.Application.Current.Windows)
        {
            if (w.IsVisible)
            {
                var helper = new WindowInteropHelper(w);
                if (helper.Handle == hwnd) return w;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    public static Window GetWindowFromMousePosition()
    {
        POINT p = new POINT();
        NativeMethods.GetCursorPos(ref p);
        return GetWindowFromPoint(new Point(p.x, p.y));
    }



    public MainWindow()
    {


        InitializeComponent();



        if (GetWindowFromMousePosition() != null)
        {

            LeftClick(System.Windows.Forms.Cursor.Position.X, System.Windows.Forms.Cursor.Position.Y);
            // mouse cursor is over window
        }
        else
        {
            LeftClickRelease(System.Windows.Forms.Cursor.Position.X, System.Windows.Forms.Cursor.Position.Y);
                // mouse cursor is somewhere else
        }
    }
}
```

}